# mysqlx python connector NoSQL can't insert date

Tags: python, datetime, mysql-x-devapi

I'm using mysqlx XDevAPI for python (NoSQL). I can't insert a date into my table.

```
table = my_schema.get_table("date_table")
field = "date_field"
insert = table.insert(field)
value = datetime.datetime.now()
insert.values(value)
insert.execute
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Expected token type 19 at pos 0 but found type 72
```

I'm presuming it's to do with the date/datetime format but I'm not sure how to find what tokens 19 or 72 are. If I try to insert a string or int I get the same error.

Comment: What is the MySQL column data type? `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or other? In any case, apparently there is no support for inserting `datetime` class instances directly but you can always stringify your values with `datetime.now().isoformat()`, for instance, and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Like Rui said, Connector/Python doesn't support Python object conversion in the X DevAPI, you need to convert the datetime to a string format before inserting.

Comment: Thanks both! I couldn’t figure out how to accept Rui’s comment as an answer. I incidentally figured this out in the end, it just seemed odd as when using MySQL connector it insisted on a datetime object.